# How to respond to notifications with methods of visible view's controller only?

Tags: ios, swift

On the first UITableViewController scene of my project I use UITextFields in cells to make some of their content possible to rename on the fly. I had to implement notification center observers to manage tableView insets when keyboard appears and hides the cell, that is being modified.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    (...)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWasShown:"), name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillBeHidden:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    (...)
}
```

I aslo put in deinit code to remove these observers:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

However when I perform a segue to another scene, and keyboard appears I recieve runtime exception 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' **with a line of the previous UItableViewController code, that should not be active on this scene**:

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
 (...)
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(editingIndexPath!) as? ListsTableViewCell { // ERROR HERE
        (...)
    }
}
```

I suppose this is because notifications run globally. But I didn't expect, that currently invisible view's controller will respond to notification with own functon.
The question is: how to force controllers react to notifications only when their view is visible. In my case deinit {} does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifecycle of a view controller is as follows:

`init` -> `loadView` -> `viewDidLoad` -> `viewWillAppear:` -> `viewDidAppear:` -> `viewWillDisappear:` -> `viewDidDisappear:` -> `deinit`

When you push or present another view controller (controller B), the current view controller (controller A) calls its `viewWillDisappear:`and `viewDidDisappear:` functions respectively, but `deinit` does not get called because the (A) is still being referenced by the navigation stack. When (B) eventually pops back or gets dismissed the methods `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` get called (A). It's only after (A) pops that `deinit` gets called.

Because of this, the notifications for the keyboard are getting fired on your view controller even though it is not currently visible.

You should move your notification registration and removal to `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` respectively.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you very much for answer!